# loop posting ajax results until they are all posted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

the below code works great for displaying in my first file

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost/website/files/userstuff/files/",
    asynch : false,
    cache : false,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a").each(function(i, el) {
            var val = $(el).attr('href');
            if (val.match(/\.(pdf|doc|docx|txt|html|js|css|rar|7zip)$/)) {
                var fileslocation = ("http://localhost/website/files/userstuff/files/" + val)
                var displayfilestable = ("<table><thead><tr><th>Files</th></tr></table>");
                var adddata = ("<tr><td><a href='"+ fileslocation +"'target='_blank'>"+ val +"</td></tr>");
                $("#filestable").html(displayfilestable)
                $("filestable, table").append(adddata);
                console.log(adddata)
            }
        });
    }
});
```

this code will as you would think pull and display the files in the table row, however it is only performing this for the first file it finds I was wondering if anyone here could help get this to display all of the files in the files folder in the table. thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNrTV.png)

Comment: can you able to post your response data

Comment: This means your server is exposing files in directories which is horribly insecure. You should fix that in server config and use server side programming language to read directories

Comment: hi charlietfl the website currently doesnt (and i dont think ever will) use a server. It is a client side website being created for a friend, it is only being run through localhost so ajax calls work

Comment: @ Kalaiselvan A  i have included a link to an image showing you the response data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code just works fine. The problems is, in that loop (each) you keep re-create table. That why it show only 1 data. Check my example based on your code.

HTML

```
 <div>
<a href="sad1.pdf">sad1.pdf</a><br>
<a href="sad2.pdf">sad2.pdf</a><br>
<a href="sad3.pdf">sad3.pdf</a>

<div id="filestable"></div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var displayfilestable = ("<table><thead><tr><th>Files</th></tr></table>");
$("#filestable").html(displayfilestable);
$("DIV").find("a").each(function(i, el) { // this is your data
    var val = $(el).attr('href');
    if (val.match(/\.(pdf|doc|docx|txt|html|js|css|rar|7zip)$/)) {
        var fileslocation = ("http://localhost/website/files/userstuff/files/" + val)
        var adddata = ("<tr><td><a href='"+ fileslocation +"'target='_blank'>"+ val +"</td></tr>");
        $("filestable, table").append(adddata);
                console.log(adddata)
    }
 });
```

AND Jsfiddle here :https://jsfiddle.net/synz/yrag1zpr/